# Why aren't these two variables equal to each other

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

string reverseString(char* str, int sizeArray)
{
char* first = &str[0];
char* last = &str[sizeArray - 1];
while(first < last)
{
    char temp = *first;
    *first = *last;
    *last = temp;
    first++;
    last--;
}
return str;

}

int main()
{
int size_of_array;
cout << "Max size of input string: ";
cin >> size_of_array;

char* someArray = new char[size_of_array];

cout << "Enter in string: ";
cin >> someArray;

while(strlen(someArray)!=size_of_array);
{
    cout << "Length of string doesn't equal size of array" << endl;
    cout << "Enter in string: ";
    cin >> someArray;
}


cout << reverseString(someArray, size_of_array);

}
```

When I cout strlen(someArray) and size_of_array they both are the same number, but when I run it I get the error in the while loop saying that they don't equal each other.

Example: I'll input 5 for size_of_array, then enter in the string Kevin. It'll give me the error.

Comment: `"Kevin"` is 6 characters, not 5.

Comment: If you're using C++, you should be using `std::string` rather than raw C-style strings...

Comment: You have a semicolon at the end of the while statement.

Comment: Well.. I feel dumb... It was the stupid semicolon I accidentally put them from a copy paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra semicolon after your while statement which ends the condition. The following code block is then run unconditionally.

Comment: Wow... That was because I used a do while loop earlier and decided to be lazy and copy paste the while loop. Thanks for finding the error! It works now.

Answer (score 0):

The actual `char` array uses a `\0` null character to placehold the end of the `char *` string, `strlen()` doesn't include this null character in it's length count.